# Discord.js V12 blacklist command using quick.db isn't working

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to make a blacklist command that won't allow anyone who uses command to use them and sends "you are blacklisted" but when someone uses the command and blacklists someone it doesn't log any error and they would still be able to use the commands what's wrong with my code?
code in the bot's main file:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    
    let user = db.get(`blacklist_${message.author.id}`);
    if(user == true) return message.channel.send('You are blacklisted!');

// rest of code
```

the blacklist command's code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const db = require('quick.db')

module.exports = {
    name: 'blacklist',
    description: 'Blacklisting/unblacklisting a user',
    args: 'true',
    usage: '<user id>',
    execute(message, args, client) {
        
        if (message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === '745415214199078942')) {
             let user = args[0];
             if (user === undefined) return message.channel.send('Invalid user or id')
             if(!user) return message.channel.send(`Invalid user or id`);
    
             let fetched = db.get(`blacklist_${user.id}`)
    
           if(!fetched) {
                 db.set(`blacklist_${user.id}`, true)
                 message.channel.send(`Blacklisted!`);
           }else{ 
                 db.delete(`blacklist_${user.id}`)
                 message.channel.send(`Unblacklisted!`);
                }
        } else {
            message.channel.send("You aren't a manager.")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only reason the users would still be able to use the commands would be if the user was not properly being added to the db, causing the following line to be `false` instead of `true`:

```
db.get(`blacklist_${message.author.id}`)
```

If your blacklist isn't working, then that line would have to *always* be a falsy value such as `undefined`. And that means `blacklist_${message.author.id}` is not properly being set to `true` in your blacklist command's code.

So let's dig into your blacklist command's code and see where exactly you are setting it to `true`. This is the line where you are doing it:

```
db.set(`blacklist_${user.id}`, true)
```

Okay, there are no syntax issues or typos there. So that means, if `blacklist_<user id>` is still `undefined` even after you are executing the above line, then the value of `user.id` must be incorrect. Because if `user.id` was correct, then obviously the value of `blacklist_<user id>` would be `true`, and if that were the case they would get the "you are blacklisted" message and be unable to use commands. So that means the value of `user.id` is incorrect.

So what exactly is the value of `user.id`? Well, what's the value of `user`? This is what you've defined it as:

```
let user = args[0];
```

Okay, so what's `args[0]`? According to your usage, that first arg is just the ID of the user to blacklist. So `args[0]` *is* the user's ID, some String in the form: `12345678901234567`. So if the variable `user` itself already represents the user's ID, why are you using `user.id`? Your code is attempting to do something like `12345678901234567.id` instead of just using the ID itself.

So that's the answer to what is wrong with your code. `user.id` doesn't exist, it's `undefined`. Your `user` variable itself *is* the user's ID, so you need to use `user` instead of `user.id` in your blacklist command's code. So this is what the fixed version would look like:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'blacklist',
    description: 'Blacklisting/unblacklisting a user',
    args: 'true',
    usage: '<user id>',
    execute(message, args, client) {
        
        if (message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === '745415214199078942')) {
             let user = args[0];
             if (!user) return message.channel.send('Invalid user or id');
    
             let fetched = db.get(`blacklist_${user}`)
    
           if (!fetched) {
                 db.set(`blacklist_${user}`, true)
                 message.channel.send(`Blacklisted!`);
           } else { 
                 db.delete(`blacklist_${user}`)
                 message.channel.send(`Unblacklisted!`);
           }
        } else {
            message.channel.send("You aren't a manager.")
        }
    }
}
```

I additionally removed the redundant line `if (user === undefined)`, because `if (!user)` already covers the case of the user being `undefined`.

Be sure to go through a debugging process on your own next time, like the step-by-step process I detailed above. It really helps to go through your code logically when you find an issue in your code, especially when it is a logical error like this one (by which I mean the code doesn't actually cause an error, but does give you a result that you did not intend).